# How to load module in background in angular 5?

Tags: angular

I'm using `angular 5` right now and i want to **load few module** in `background` ?.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: what exactly you mean by load in background? Can you provide your scenario?

Comment: can you elaborate the post

Comment: Yes, When i open angular website first load immediately home page and which module upcoming  after that... i want to that module load in background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use lazy loading. With lazy loading you can set it up to load only your first root app module so the app comes up quickly. You can then use lazy loading to load all of the other modules either on-demand or asynchronously in the background.

You can follow along with an example in the Angular docs here: https://angular.io/guide/router#preloading-background-loading-of-feature-areas

I have a complete code example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
            {
                path: 'products',
                canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
                data: { preload: true },
                loadChildren: 'app/products/product.module#ProductModule'
            },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
        ], { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }) // , { enableTracing: true })
    ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Too bad we don't have access to your C:\ drive.